# Is there a general function or way in Java to calculate an equation of the form (a+b+...+n)^2 with a,b,n >= 0?

Tags: java, math, equation

I need to find a way to implement an algorithm in Java that can calculate (a+b+...+n)^2 with a,b,n >= 0. The purpose is to use it afterwards in order to calculate Jain's Fairness index for my algorithm in networks. Is there any standard way to do that or any specific library for advanced math that i might have missed?

Comment: what do you mean by ... ?

Comment: You mean like `sum = a + b + … + n; return sum * sum`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the sequence (a, b, ..., n) an arithmetic progression (e.g. 5, 10, 15, 20). If so, it's important that you say so.

Answer (score 1):

Just sum those n values in for loop and then multiply it by itself. Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The number of possible problems you may encounter is infinite, so you should not be surprised if you often get into a situation where there is no method to help you. Let's suppose that you have an array of numbers, let's suppose it has `double` elements and the name of the array is `input`, then:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < input.length; index++)
    sum += input[index];
double result = Math.pow(sum, 2);
//output holds the result
```

If there is a possibility of overflow, then you will need to handle it. Also, you will need to handle the validation that your items are positive.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Oups, I thought the op wants the latter, sorry. Please see my edit.